# Should I use Japanese title for Japanese people instead of English title?

Tags: etiquette

I'm in contact with a Japanese student support staff of a Japanese university. Because he is a staff, I don't know how to address him properly: *Mr.* or *Dr.* or *Prof.* However, I know that in Japanese culture, there is only one title for this job: *sensei*:

> **sensei**: (for example Sato-sensei)
>   This is a title used for teachers, doctors and other people with a higher education and from **whom you receive a service or instructions**.
>   [www.japan-guide.com](http://www.japan-guide.com/e/e2271.html)

As a member of the Sinosphere culture, I understand that correct title is important. Also, this would indicate that I'm trying to learn how the culture works, even thought I don't know Japanese.

Should I?

Comment: "I'm trying to learn how the culture works". Why? Are you studying in Japan? And call a student support staff as "sensei"? He is probably an administrative employee and calling them sensei makes no sense.

Comment: Unless you write your email in Japanese, use Japanese title in an English email is very weird. Even if you use it correctly, this will not impress anyone. (I worked in Japan before, and I have 2kyu in Japanese)

Comment: @Alexandros see the definition of *sensei* above

Comment: @qsp virmaior says that you can. Can you go there and discuss why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are writing in English, I would say

1. The expected* way to address university staff (non-faculty) is
   generally "Mr" or "Ms" depending on their gender.
2. You *can* call
   people who you would call sensei in Japanese by [family name]-Sensei
   (note the position of the sensei as after) in English.
3. Calling people with doctorates "Dr X" is **not** generally expected in
       Japan. (Also, many Japanese faculty who are older don't have doctorates due to some vagaries of the system used here).
4. Similarly, they are much less used to "Professor X" than
       in American contexts.

*I would say (2) is normal in day-to-day conversation, but for many of them writing = Mr / Ms*

Separately, if he is truly "support staff," then he is not a *sensei* within the Japanese system. If he is over the support staff, that might not be true.

---

*by "expected" I mean the expectation of most Japanese users of English

Source: 1kyu (JPLT N1) and presently living in Japan working at a university

Comment: so it is at least no harm for me by using *sensei*? Also, based on the source I've given above, why is *sensei* not suitable for him? Which title should I use instead? *san*?

Comment: I don't know if I would say "no harm." It doesn't make you look smart to write sensei in English in  the first place. When Japanese people use English, some go so far as to try translating words that exist in the rest of the world already "sushi" as "raw fish", etc. / similarly, san is so generic and odd to use in English writing that it will just make you look like a japanophile.

Comment: In terms of why sensei is inappropriate for *staff*, the answer is that *sensei* means teacher and places that person above you as someone you revere. If he's admin staff, then he's not your teacher and it's kind of weird to revere him even if you should respect him. He's an office worker at a university != sensei.

Comment: I LOLed at the "japanophile"